# Tense usage? What to use in future situation?

Tags: conditionnel

I'm confused by the conditional tense in French, for instance...

"Dans l’avenir, je ne **serais** pas surpris si les nations ***disparaissent*** et ***sont*** remplacées par les organisations a l’échelle planétaire."

What would be the correct tenses of the bolded verbs? Would they all be in the conditional tense, or would they be subjunctive (since its hypothetical?) Or...

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure why you talk about the subjunctive since there is no subjunctive in the sentence you give.

It is, as you correctly tagged and used, a conditional.

With the conditional, you have to use the indicative present, as you did, or the *imparfait* tense, which are both correct sequences of tenses.

Here it is with the imparfait, which appears more *natural* to me, although your example is also correct:

> Dans l’avenir, je ne *serais* pas surpris si les nations *disparaissaient* et *étaient* remplacées par les organisations a l’échelle planétaire.

Answer (score 6):

This is just an extension of Subtenante's answer:

And if you replace *si* by *que* (*I wouldn't be surprised if* becomes *I wouldn't be surprised that*), you have to use the subjunctive:

> A l’avenir, je ne serais pas surpris que les nations disparaissent et soient remplacées par les organisations a l’échelle planétaire.

Comment: Pour moi, « à l'avenir » est plus un synonyme de « dorénavant, » avec son implication de changement.  Je ne crois pas que ce soit le bon choix de mots, car ça implique que ce matin encore, ça te surprenait, non ?

Comment: Peut-être qu'*à court/long/moyen terme* serait plus approprié et plus précis, mais à défaut de cette précision, *à l'avenir* me semble coller. C'est vrai qu'il peut-être utilisé comme *dorénavant*, mais je crois pas que ce sens est exclusif.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

> Dans l’avenir, je ne serais pas surpris si les nations disparaissent
>   et sont remplacées par les organisations a l’échelle planétaire.

you should write:

> Je ne serais pas surpris si, dans le futur, les nations **disparaissaient** *(imparfait)* et **étaient** *(imparfait)* remplacées par des organisations à l'échelle planétaire.

It's a question of "concordance des temps".
A similar question has already be asked here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-ne-serais-pas-surpris-que-si.1036006/?hl=fr

But you can also write:

> Je ne serais pas surpris que, dans le futur, les nations **disparaissent** *(subjonctif présent)* et **soient** *(subjonctif présent)* remplacées par des organisations à l'échelle planétaire.

"Dans l'avenir" doesn't sound French.
"A l'avenir" and "Dans le futur" are correct.
"A l'avenir" is synonymous of "Désormais" (From now).
But "Dans un proche avenir" or "Dans un lointain avenir" are correct if you are telling about the future.